# Changing the order of the words in a file when they are on different lines

Tags: java, file

I want to exchange the postion of some strings in a file.This is the input:

```
 Student learns programming 
 java. Teacher rates 
 student.
```

I want to change the order of the last two words in a sentence of 4 words.It is OK if there is a single line,but how do I do when I got 2 lines:for example I want to change the order of programming and java and the expected output is like this:

```
 Student learns java
 programming.Teacher rates
 student.
```

I tried something like this(part of the code where the inversion is made,but the output is an empty file):

```
        public static void changeOrd(File f,File out) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream _inp=new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedReader _readin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_inp));
    PrintWriter _prt=new PrintWriter(out);
    BufferedWriter _buffwriter=new BufferedWriter(_prt);
    String _string=_readin.readLine();
    while(_string!=null)
    {
      String[] _v=_string.split(" ");
      int increm=0,i=0;
      while(!_v[i+1].endsWith("."))
      {
          _buffwriter.write(_v[i]+" "); 
          increm++;
          i++;
      }
      if(i==2 && _v[i+1]!=null){

          _buffwriter.write(_v[i+1]+" ");
          _buffwriter.write(_v[i]+" ");

      }
      _string=_readin.readLine();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Put the words into a String array as you read them.  Keep track of the number of words per input line in an int array.  Swap words.  Output the same number of words per line from the String array using the int array.

Answer (score 0):

Call `flush` and `close` on all top-level streams/writers/readers
at the end of your processing. Or just call `close`. This should
solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing or closing the output stream:

```
_buffwriter.flush();
_buffwriter.close();
```

You should finally close all of your streams indeed:

```
BufferedWriter _buffwriter= null;
try {
    _buffwriter=new BufferedWriter(_prt);
    // the rest of your code

} finally {
    if (_buffwriter != null) {
        _buffwriter.close();
    }
}
```

Use the same treatment with each stream (_inp, etc).

Comment: yes I forgot that,but do you have any ideas about when the the sentence is on different lines?I tought about having two arrays one for the first line and one for the second.